# MySQL fails to install with a year 2038 Problem

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL on my Linux machine but it fails to install and throws following error

> 'This MySql server doesn't support dates later then 2038'

What can I possibly do to solve this problem or should I just wait for Oracle to patch this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nasty.
It really depends on what the column is used for.

You could store all date/times in ISO standard string format
YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.ssssssssZ, then convert it for comparison purposes in code using a 64 bit long long.

Hopefully year 9999 is enough? :-)

Storing datestamps as canonical strings supports comparison, indexing, but you have to do your own validation.

Comment: I looked into the source code of Mysql and time_t is 64 bit but they have put check on the date. So if your machine date is more than 2038 it throws the above error. I wonder if commenting that check would do the wonder?

Comment: It might, there are no guarantees with time_t implementation consistency between OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you installed the mysql server on a Operating System where there is a 32bits bottleneck. It means your datetime would be stored in a 32 bits datatype and during 2038 this datatype is going to reach the limit of the 32bits. It would require to get more bits to store datetime neyond the year 2038. This issue is known as being the 2038 year bug.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 0):

On my (virtual) machine running mysql the clock was for some reason changed to year 2222, causing this issue.

```
root@ubuntu:~# date
Fri Mar  1 02:01:05 UTC 2222
```

I fixed it by changing date back to normal:

```
date +%Y%m%d -s "20201116"
```